# Leaflet Layer Control: Dynamically Adding and Removing Layer Controls

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to add Layer's Control in Leaflet Javascript library; for reference, please see this: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#control-layers . My code works fine for the most part: I have a `layerControl` object which gets initialized with `baseLayers` but no Overlay yet. Then I add a `layer_USA_Counties` Overlay as in the code below. So far so good.

But I need to be able to add a new `isochronesGroup` overlay to the layerControl object. That code works fine except that in subsequent code executions the isochronesGroup keeps adding to the control--please see this screen capture. I can remove the control using the commented out command but it would, of course, also remove all `isochronesGroup` controls, thus not displaying it at all. Please note: The loaded layers and their controls don't have to be of the `layerGroup`() type.

[image]

```
//globally set
var baseLayers = {
        "Grayscale": grayscale,
        "Streets": streets
 };     
layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers, null, { collapsed: false }).addTo(map);

//add a layer from a WMS call and add to the layerControl object
map_LayerGroup = L.layerGroup().addLayer(layer_USA_Counties);///.addTo(map);   
layerControl.addOverlay(map_LayerGroup, "USA Counties");

//Following code gets executed again and again based on user interaction        
isochronesGroup = L.layerGroup().addLayer(route_lines).addTo(map);
layerControl.addOverlay(isochronesGroup, "Isochrones");
///layerControl.removeLayer(isochronesGroup); //WORKS If already created. Or errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing. It's a hack but works. Later, I will make this as part of some maintenance function to add/remove the Control's options as needed. The code in the Question remains the same except the following part has changed. Basically, I am recreating the Control.

HTH

```
//Following code gets executed again and again based on user interaction
//Remove the control entirely! 
layerControl.remove();
//Add the control back with baseLayers
layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers, null, { collapsed: false }).addTo(map);
//Add back the USA Counties Overlay Control
usa_counties_LayerGroup = L.layerGroup().addLayer(layer_USA_Counties);///.addTo(map); 
layerControl.addOverlay(usa_counties_LayerGroup, "USA Counties");
//Add the isochronesGroup Overlay Control
isochronesGroup = L.layerGroup().addLayer(route_lines).addTo(map);
layerControl.addOverlay(isochronesGroup, "Isochrones");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this without having to recreate the control each time.  The problem is that the `isochronesGroup` LayerGroup is being recreated, which means you lose track of the layers that have already been added to the control.  Try stepping through this example in the browser console:

```
layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers, null, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);

isochronesGroup = L.layerGroup().addLayer(route_lines).addTo(map);
layerControl.addOverlay(isochronesGroup, "I1");    // Adds I1
layerControl.addOverlay(isochronesGroup, "I2");    // Adds I2
layerControl.removeLayer(isochronesGroup);         // Removes I1
layerControl.removeLayer(isochronesGroup);         // Removes I2
layerControl.removeLayer(isochronesGroup);         // No effect (and no error)
layerControl.removeLayer(wibble);                  // Error
```

You should see that although you get duplicate entries in the layer control, the repeated calls to `removeLayer()` eventually remove them all. This works because the variable `isochronesGroup` refers to the same object the whole time. It's not a problem to call `removeLayer()` an extra time, even when all the layers are gone from the control, so long as `isochronesGroup` is actually defined as a valid layer. Now try this:

```
layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers, null, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);

isochronesGroup = L.layerGroup().addLayer(route_lines).addTo(map);
layerControl.addOverlay(isochronesGroup, "I1");    // Adds I1
isochronesGroup = L.layerGroup().addLayer(route_lines).addTo(map);
layerControl.addOverlay(isochronesGroup, "I2");    // Adds I2
layerControl.removeLayer(isochronesGroup);         // Removes I2
layerControl.removeLayer(isochronesGroup);         // No effect
layerControl.removeLayer(isochronesGroup);         // No effect
```

In the above example, I2 gets removed from the control, but I1 stays.  This is because  `isochronesGroup` has been redefined, and is now a different object to the one that was added to the control with the label I1.

With the above in mind, here are two more elegant ways to work around your problem:

1. When you need to create a new `isochronesGroup` layer, remove the old one from the Layer Control immediately beforehand, while the `isochronesGroup` variable still refers to the old layer object.
2. Rather than redefining the `isochronesGroup` LayerGroup each time, re-use the object, but use `clearLayers()`, `removeLayer()` and `addLayer()` to change which layers it contains.

Using the second approach, you don't have to keep changing the Layer Control. e.g.

```
// Initialisation
isochronesGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);           // Create empty LayerGroup
layerControl.addOverlay(isochronesGroup, "Isochrones");  // Add group to control

// Code to call repeatedly
isochronesGroup.clearLayers().addLayer(route_lines);
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you sir! I tried your 'second approach' suggestion but getting an ` TypeError: layerControl.addLayer is not a function` error. I think I should stick with what I have for now. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  That `addLayer()` should have been `addOverlay()`.  I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the continuing help and the support! So I implemented the correct 'second approach' code block as above and the error went away but the original problem of keeping adding the isochrones options has come back.